# Migrations are pending. Unable to create more models ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

How to create more models in ruby on rails? at first create one model like this type of command:

```
$ rails g model user name:string email:string
```

Create properly, but when I try to create second model like this type of command:

```
$ rails g model job job1:string job2:string
```

Not create any model & showing this type of error

```
 Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run: bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development
```

How can I solve this issue? I'm using `Rails 4.2.5`, `ruby 2.1.7p400` & `mysql`

Comment: The message you are getting tells you exactly how to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error you are getting `Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue,...`

To fix this you need to follow the below step.

1: In terminal you need to Run

```
rake db:migrate # in order to run the all pending migration task
```

2: Then

```
rails g model job job1:string job2:string
```

Should work!!!

hope this solve your issue!!!

Answer (score 0):

Do a `rake db:migrate` in your terminal every time you generate a model(s) or make some changes in your model. Only then it will be applied to your rails app. 
For more on migration you can visit: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/migrations.html

Answer (score 0):

Each time you create a migration or/and add a model (or any changes to your table) you have to run `rake db:migrate` to apply those changes.

You can also see which migrations are pending by using `rake db:migrate:status`

Hope it sheds a bit of light on your issue.